# The Checkbox opens link onClick when form is submitted, but how do I post the form at the same time?

Tags: php, javascript, post, checkbox, onclick

I am trying to build a downloads section where the visitor completes a form and then selects check boxes to open download dialogs.

I would like the form to submit and the dialogs to open, when the button is clicked.

I am not very good at writing scripts, although I can read them. Currently I can only get one or the other to work!

The form is a standard PHP form....

**This is the javascript I am using**

```
var suffix=1;
function downloadAll(oFrm){
var oChk = oFrm.elements["file"+(suffix++)];
if (oChk){
if (oChk.checked){
location.href = oChk.value;
setTimeout(function(){downloadAll(oFrm)}, 2000);
}
else{
downloadAll(oFrm);
}
}
}
```

**This is an abbreviated part of my HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="file1" id="file1" value="/download.php?f=blank.gif" /><label for="file1">blank.gif</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="file2" id="file2" value="/download.php?f=atlas_blue_hover2.png" /><label for="file2">atlas_blue_hover2.png</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="file3" id="file3" value="/download.php?f=Tabs.css" /><label for="file3">Tabs.css</label>
<input type="button" value="Download All" onClick="suffix=1;downloadAll(this.form);return false;" />
```

I think that this might not be working because the onclick cancels out post in a PHP form

```
method="post" action="http://url"
```

Can I do similar to above using onSubmit? Or using the checkbox values in PHP?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return false from your onclick handler. That cancels the default action

Comment: Thank you Keith but this has not worked.

I have tried return true, and getting rid of the return. 

Both, stops the javascript from working but allows the PHP form to post its action!

Comment: Main the button type Submit instead of Button also.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Nissan Man I have tried

<input value="Submit" type="submit" onClick="suffix=1;downloadAll(this.form); return false;" /> 

opens javascript and 

<input value="Submit" type="submit" onClick="suffix=1;downloadAll(this.form);" /> 

posts the form action

I still can't do both...
any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Return true; as he noted in his answer.

Comment: Return True also still posts the form action without activating the javascript

Comment: What exactly is downloadAll doing? Is it just opening a new window? As soon as the post to the server occurs, the entire page will be refreshed.

Comment: Yes it opens a download dialog, Thanks

Comment: Looking at the downloadAll function, you don't ever popup a new window for the download. You set location.href, which just redirects the current page. If you want a download dialog, you will need to use window.open